# Can someone explain part of this code found in the Pebble C Watchface tutorial?

Tags: c, function, pebble-watch, shorthand, pebble-sdk

I'm looking into the Pebble C watch face tutorial found here https://developer.getpebble.com/tutorials/watchface-tutorial/part1

The part of code in question is here:

```
static void init() {
  // Create main Window element and assign to pointer
  s_main_window = window_create();

  // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
  window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });

  // Show the Window on the watch, with animated=true
  window_stack_push(s_main_window, true);
}
```

**Is window_set_window_handlers a function declaration and call? And what is the terminology for the .load and .unload shorthand notation in C?**

Would greatly appreciate if someone could possibly explain that snippet of code, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). The struct [`WindowHandlers`](https://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/User_Interface/Window/#WindowHandlers) is created and initialized inline before being passed to the function call of [`window_set_window_handlers`](https://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/User_Interface/Window/#window_set_window_handlers).